# How do I create multiple plots by looping through a vertical data frame in R?

Tags: r, loops

This is my first question here, so if I did something wrong let me know and I will fix it. I already searched the site and couldn't find an answer that was satisfactory to my problem.

I have a big dataframe with 5 columns; Genotype, Time, phenotype-x, phenotype-y and phenotype-z. My aim is to produce and save graphs with ggtern for each time point containing all genotypes for x, y and z.
Right now I filter my data for a certain time point to get a satisfactory graph.

However, I do not feel like filtering my dataset manually for all the 338 time points I have. I think that would be done best with a loop, this is where I get confused.

I have always learned that datasets should be saved in a vertical way. However, the answers I have found with for-loops are used to loop through all (or a subset of) the columns. I would like to loop through each time point within one column. I know changing my dataframe to horizontal can be done with a variety of methods, but I would like to learn to do it with vertical datasets if possible.

This is the code I have so far:

```
data <- read.table("dataset.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(Time=="a_time_point" ) 

plot <- ggtern(data, mapping = aes(x = phenotype-x, y = phenotype-y, z = phenotype-z)) +
                 geom_point(aes(colour=Genotype)) 

png("Ternary_Plot.png", width = 6.5, height = 3.5, units = 'in', res = 300)
plot(plot)
dev.off()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I doesn't matter wether you loop over columns or rows. Simply loop over unique timepoints in your data and put your code inside the loop. You only have to change the filter statement and add a identifier for time to your filename.

Comment: Hi thank you, how do I simply loop over unique timepoints?

Comment: Basically the same as @AndreasM suggested in this answer. However, instead of looping over `dat$Time` which means looping over single rows I would suggest to loop over unique timepoints i.e. `unqiue(dat$Time)`

Comment: True. That was an oversight. The loop should of course run only over the unique time points. I edited it to do so. Thanks!

Comment: I will look into that as well, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this what you want?

Edited to let the loop run over unique time points (as rightly pointed in the comments above).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)

#make some sample data
dat <- expand.grid(Genotype = c("A", "B", "C"), Time = 1:5)
dat <- cbind(dat, x = rnorm(15), y = rnorm(15), z = rnorm(15))

#save one plot per time point
for (iTime in unique(dat$Time)) {
  xdat <- dat %>%filter(Time==iTime)
  
  plot <- ggtern(xdat, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=Genotype)) 
  
  fileName <- paste0("Ternary_Plot", sprintf("%03d", iTime), ".png")
  
  png(fileName, width = 6.5, height = 3.5, units = 'in', res = 300)
  plot(plot)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Hi! It gives me an error regarding xdat: "Error in ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping, environment = environment,  :   object 'xdat' not found"

Comment: Hmm. That is odd. When I copy and paste my code above in a new R-session, it runs without problem for me... "xdat" is created inside the loop by subsetting the sample data frame dat. The error message suggest that `xdat <- dat %>%filter(Time==iTime)` did not create an object. Why, I have no idea. You could try replacing this with `xdat <- dat[dat$Time == iTime,]`. I had just used the pipe+filter version because it was in your code snippet.

Comment: I had to restart my R, there was nothing wrong with the line of code. However I can't find the saved files now? edit: Never mind, i had to restart again to make it work! thank you for your help :)